# Parsing large XML from server while downloading with LibXML2 in Swift 3

Tags: ios, c, xml, swift, libxml2

I have a Problem with the SAX parser from LibXML2 in Swift 3.
I want something like `XMLPullParser` from Android in iOS. Which downloads XML from a server and while downloading it parses the Stream.

My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ResultList id="12345678-0" platforms="A;B;C;D;E">
    <Book id="1111111111" author="Author A" title="Title A" price="9.95" ... />
    <Book id="1111111112" author="Author B" title="Title B" price="2.00" ... />
    <Book id="1111111113" author="Author C" title="Title C" price="5.00" ... />
    <ResultInfo bookcount="3" />
</ResultList>
```

So all the data is stored in attributes rather than child nodes.

I've made the following class by myself mostly based by these examples:
[XMLPerformance](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/XMLPerformance/Introduction/Intro.html), [XMLPerformance-Swift](https://github.com/FTS-InfoTech/XMLPerformance-Swift) and [iOS-XML-Streaming](https://github.com/robertmryan/iOS-XML-Streaming-w-Base64-Decode)

```
import Foundation

class LibXMLParser: NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate {

    var url: URL?
    var delegate: LibXMLParserDelegate?
    var done = false
    var context: xmlParserCtxtPtr?

    var simpleSAXHandlerStruct: xmlSAXHandler = {
        var handler = xmlSAXHandler()

        handler.initialized = XML_SAX2_MAGIC
        handler.startElementNs = startElementSAX
        handler.endElementNs = endElementSAX
        handler.characters = charactersFoundSAX
        //handler.error = errorEncounteredSAX

        return handler
    }()

    init(url: URL) {
        super.init()

        self.url = url
    }

    func parse() {
        self.done = false
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: url!))
        dataTask.resume()

        self.context = xmlCreatePushParserCtxt(&simpleSAXHandlerStruct, Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque(), nil, 0, nil)
        self.delegate?.parserDidStartDocument()

        repeat {
            RunLoop.current.run(mode: .defaultRunLoopMode, before: Date.distantFuture)
        } while !self.done

        xmlFreeParserCtxt(self.context)
        self.delegate?.parserDidEndDocument()
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
        print("Did receive data")
        data.withUnsafeBytes { (bytes: UnsafePointer<CChar>) -> Void in
            xmlParseChunk(self.context, bytes, CInt(data.count), 0)
        }
    }

    func urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession session: URLSession) {
        xmlParseChunk(self.context, nil, 0, 1)
        self.done = true
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didBecomeInvalidWithError error: Error?) {
        self.done = true
        //self.delegate?.parserErrorOccurred(error)
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        self.done = true
        //self.delegate?.parserErrorOccurred(error)
    }
}

private func startElementSAX(_ ctx: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, name: UnsafePointer<xmlChar>?, prefix: UnsafePointer<xmlChar>?, URI: UnsafePointer<xmlChar>?, nb_namespaces: CInt, namespaces: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<xmlChar>?>?, nb_attributes: CInt, nb_defaulted: CInt, attributes: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<xmlChar>?>?) {
    let parser = Unmanaged<LibXMLParser>.fromOpaque(ctx!).takeUnretainedValue()
    parser.delegate?.parserDidStartElement(String(cString: name!), nb_attributes: nb_attributes, attributes: attributes)
}

private func endElementSAX(_ ctx: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, name: UnsafePointer<xmlChar>?,
                           prefix: UnsafePointer<xmlChar>?,
                           URI: UnsafePointer<xmlChar>?) {
    let parser = Unmanaged<LibXMLParser>.fromOpaque(ctx!).takeUnretainedValue()
    parser.delegate?.parserDidEndElement(String(cString: name!))
}

private func charactersFoundSAX(_ ctx: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, ch: UnsafePointer<xmlChar>?, len: CInt) {
    let parser = Unmanaged<LibXMLParser>.fromOpaque(ctx!).takeUnretainedValue()
    parser.delegate?.parserFoundCharacters(String(cString: ch!))
}
```

I initialize this class with an `URL`. When i call `parse()` it creates a `URLSession` and a `URLSessionDataTask` with an delegate to self to override the method `didReceive data: Data`.
After that i create a `xmlParserCtxtPtr` and loop until the dataTask is finished.

When it receives data I parse it with the `xmlParseChunk` method and `startElementSAX` calls the delegate that I've set from a ViewController class. (I just need the element name, number of attributes and attributes.)
So far so good.

In my ViewController (UITableViewController) I have the following code:

```
func downloadBooksLibXML() {
    print("Downloading…")
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        print("Setting up parser")
        let parser = LibXMLParser(url: URL(string: self.baseUrl + self.parameters!)!)
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()
    }
}

func parserDidStartDocument() {

}

func parserDidEndDocument() {
    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        self.isDone = true
        print("Finished")
    }
}

func parserDidStartElement(_ elementName: String, nb_attributes: CInt, attributes: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<xmlChar>?>?) {
    print(elementName)
    switch elementName {
    case "Book":
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let book = self.buildBook(nb_attributes: nb_attributes, attributes: attributes)
            self.books.append(book)

            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.books.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
            self.navigationItem.title = String(format: NSLocalizedString("books_found", comment: "Books found"), "\(self.books.count)")
        }
    case "ResultList":
        break
    case "ResultInfo":
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}

func buildBook(nb_attributes: CInt, attributes: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<xmlChar>?>?) -> Book {
    let fields = 5 /* (localname/prefix/URI/value/end) */
    let book = Book()
    for i in 0..<Int(nb_attributes) {
        if let localname = attributes?[i * fields + 0],
            //let prefix = attributes?[i * fields + 1],
            //let URI = attributes?[i * fields + 2],
            let value_start = attributes?[i * fields + 3],
            let value_end = attributes?[i * fields + 4] {

            let localnameString = String(cString: localname)
            let string_start = String(cString: value_start)
            let string_end = String(cString: value_end)
            let diff = string_start.characters.count - string_end.characters.count
            if diff > 0 {
                let value = string_start.substring(to: string_start.index(string_start.startIndex, offsetBy: diff))
                book.setValue(value, forKey: localnameString)
            }
        }
    }
    return book
}

func parserDidEndElement(_ elementName: String) {

}

func parserFoundCharacters(_ string: String) {

}

func parserErrorOccurred(_ parseError: Error?) {

}
```

## ------

## Update

So the problem getting the attribute values has been fixed by the answer from nwellnhof. I've updated my code above to a much better code. It doesn't iterate through all the attributes now anymore.
Now my new problem:

I've created the method `buildBook` to get a `Book` object of the XML attributes.
I've mostly translated the method from here [What is the right way to get attribute value in libXML sax parser (C++)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25688162/6808319) to Swift and used `setValue(value: Any?, forKey: String)` to set the attributes of my book object.

But now my problem is that it doesn't update the tableView.
I've tried executing the `buildBook` method synchronous in a background thread using `DispatchQueue.global().sync` and the tableView update in an asynchronous main thread using `DispatchQueue.main.async`. But then it crashes at `tableView.endUpdates()` although it's in the main thread.

## ------

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a simple off-by-one error. To iterate the attributes array in C, I'd write something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nb_attributes; i++)
```

But you're using the [closed range operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID74) which includes the upper bound:

```
for i in 0...Int(nb_attributes)
```

So you should use the [half-open range operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID75) instead:

```
for i in 0..<Int(nb_attributes)
```

By the way, *libxml2* also has a [pull parser interface](http://xmlsoft.org/xmlreader.html) modeled after C#'s `XmlTextReader` which is much easier to use than the SAX parser.

Comment: Yeah, it was the off-by-one error. Much thanks that you found this. But now i have another problem. I've updated my question. Maybe you know a solution for this? Or maybe you have a tutorial how to use the XmlTextReader for iOS (Swift (3) or Obj-C)?

Comment: @ElegyD If you have a different problem, it's better to ask a separate question.